# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory for pictures on Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am a beginner on Python.
I try to open a picture to print its size and format.
My picture is in several folders:

- my images
- the folder of my Python codes
- the folder of `anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL`

I have already wrote only the name of the picture, then the exact path but nothing works (my picture is in `.jpg`).

Here is my code :

```py
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("v")    
print("nbr of columns and lines", image.size, image.format)
data = list(image.getdata())
print(data[:30])
```

and my error message:

> runfile('C:/Users/Optimal Conseil/.spyder-py3/temp.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/Optimal Conseil/.spyder-py3') Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Optimal Conseil.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 4, in
>   
>       image=Image.open("v")
>
> File "C:\Users\Optimal
>   Conseil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2809, in open
>       fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'v'

Comment: There is no file named "v". You should give the full file name, if the file is in the same folder as that of this code: then `image=Image.open("v.jpg")` or give the full path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image file "v" is in the same folder as your python code, your code should load it. The error shows it is missing the file. I would recommend checking for file extensions (maybe file name is "v.jpg").
And if your file is not in the python folder and is in a different folder,
the easiest way is to include the full address to your image file:

```
image=Image.open("full_path_to_file/"+"v")
```

The same approach with better practice would be like this:

```
import os
image=Image.open(os.path.join("full_path_to_file", "v"))
```

You can also use the relational address to file. "../" will take you to one directory above your current directory. For example, if your file directory structure is:

- directory

  - |
  - v.jpg
  - subdirectory

    - |
    - your_python_code.py

You can use:

```
image=Image.open("../v")
```